Is it possible to create thumbnails for Word documents and Excel sheet files?
I'm trying to create thumbnail previews when uploading different file types.
I've done it for PDFs where you render the first page as the thumbnail. But I'm quite stuck on how to do it for Microsoft documents such as Word docx and xsls files.
For the PDFs, I just used the pdfx package to render the first page and wrap that in a Container with decoration. I'd like to create something that will render the first page for Microsoft documents.

@KJ Thanks for the directions! I think it's hard to do for docx and excel files because we need a screenshot of the page. What you suggested with the stored thumbnail could work. I'll explore that option. Many thanks!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@KJ we went with not showing a thumbnail for MS files. It's too much of a hassle for something the user will see for a couple of seconds before moving on. Thanks for all the help and suggestions!
